# Axios fails CORS but fetch works fine

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, cors, nuxt.js

I've looked through all the other questions regarding CORS errors with no luck. I'm making a simple POST request in a NuxtJS client application. If I use axios, I get CORS errors, but if I use fetch, it works just fine. I would like to use axios, but I can't sort this out. The server has the correct "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers set (neither option below works when that header is removed). Anyone know why this would work for fetch but not axios?

**FAILS**

```
await this.$axios({
      url,
      method: 'POST',
      data
    })
```

**WORKS**

```
await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
```

**Error message:**
Access to XMLHttpRequest at {URL} from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In the network tab of Chrome, the request headers show as follows:

[Axios request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbZwd.png)

[fetch request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAEjR.png)

Comment: What is `data`? A string? An object? A FormData object? A Blob object?

Comment: Have you looked at the request headers from `fetch` and `axios`? Are they equal?

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly copied the fetch request initially. "data" is a javascript object. Axios takes an object, but for fetch, I stringified it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you send data in the body of an HTTP request, the request's `Content-Type` header specifies what type of data you are sending.

Since you are sending JSON the header should be `Content-Type: application/json`.

Since you are passing an object to `axios`, it encodes it as JSON and sets the proper `Content-Type` header automatically.

`fetch` doesn't do this automatically, you have to encode the data and set the `Content-Type` yourself. You've only done the first of these, so `fetch` is defaulting to claiming that you are sending plain text instead of JSON.

Your `fetch` code is in error.

---

For historical reasons, there are no special CORS requirements when you POST data using a format that you could send with a regular HTML form. `text/plain` is such a format.

Since `application/json` is not, the browser asks permission from the server using a [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

The server is not granting that permission.

It needs to respond with something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.bar.org
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

Comment: If my fetch code is wrong, why is that one working while the axios call is failing?

Comment: Because the fetch code is lying about what it is sending but the server is processing it as JSON despite the claim it is plain text.

Comment: Ah, I see. And CORS is being enforced for axios because it's automatically setting the correct "Content-Type: application/json" header. So if I correctly set the header in my fetch request, it should fail just like the axios call. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Just tested it. Yeah, the fetch failed when I set the Content-Type header. Now I just need to fix the CORS issues for both of them haha.

Comment: Legend, I missed this somehow... great explanation!

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `withCredentials`:

```
axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://....",
    data: {},
    withCredentials: true
})
```

Comment: That definitely will not help. `withCredentials` mandates a preflight request, and the preflight request is failing.